# Dynamic TextField should accept numeric characters Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have created the `textfield` dynamically, like 15 text field.By clicking next button i want to check whether the user has entered the numeric characters or not.Please help me to do this .I know ho to do this for `textfield` which is created in storyboard .But i dont know through programming for dynamic textfields.

Here is my code ,

```
 //Creating TextField

    UITextField *metaData_txt = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    metaData_txt.frame = CGRectMake(xPosOfTxt,yPosOfTxt , widthOfTxt, heightOfTxt);
    metaData_txt.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    metaData_txt.layer.borderWidth =1.0;
    metaData_txt.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    metaData_txt.tag = (txtTagBaseVaue +i);
       [self.metaData_txt setDelegate:self];       
          [self.sub_View addSubview:metaData_txt];
```

..checking numeric numeric characters on clickiing next button

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    NSArray *subviews = [self.sub_View subviews];

    for (UIView *newView in subviews) {
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {

              NSInteger tag = newView.tag;
            int index = tag - 100;


            FieldData *fieldData = [self.metaDataArray objectAtIndex:index];
       if (textField.text.length == 0) {

                     [self.view makeToast:label duration:1.0 position:CSToastPositionCenter];
                    NSLog(@"enter characters");

                }


                else if (textField.text.length > 0)
                {
               NSString *feildValue  = [self formatTypeToString:fieldData.fieldAttribute];
                    NSString *numeric = @"NUMERIC";

                    if (feildValue == numeric) {


                        [self textField:textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:<#(NSRange)#> replacementString:<#(nonnull NSString *)#>];


                    }
```

i have written the `shouldchangechractersin` range method also :
i dont what range and string i have to give , while calling the below method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
   {
    if (!string.length)
    return YES;

if (textField)
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
    if (numberOfMatches == 0)
        return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: all text field should be Numeric or not?

Comment: not all the fields , i deciding which field should be numeric ,and which field should be alpha by line   NSString *feildValue  = [self formatTypeToString:fieldData.fieldAttribute];
                NSString *numeric = @"NUMERIC";
i am getting from server

Comment: now if the field is numeric means , how can i check and set the condition for that

Comment: FieldData *fieldData = [self.metaDataArray objectAtIndex:index];
 if (textField.text.length == 0)  in this where you declare that textField